# TensorFlow : c++ custom op official example zero_out : Error

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, bazel

I have recently wanted to try out custom op in c++. I built the latest Tensorflow 2.5.0-rc3 from source in a virtual environment. Then I pip installed that source build in the environment and run code in Jupyter-lab in the environment. The op was successfully built into an `.so` file which I could load also successfully with :
`tf.load_op_library`

However, when I tried running it has the following error : `Could not find device for node`

[image]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4c2618461ead> in <module>
----> 1 zero_out_module.zero_out([2,3])

<string> in zero_out(to_zero, name)

<string> in zero_out_eager_fallback(to_zero, name, ctx)

~/Desktop/my-project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

NotFoundError: Could not find device for node: {{node ZeroOut}} = ZeroOut[]
All kernels registered for op ZeroOut:
  <no registered kernels>
 [Op:ZeroOut]
```

I load up the custom op through its full path as :

`zero_out_module =tf.load_op_library('/home/tong/Desktop/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so')`

which is different from the official example of :

`zero_out_module =tf.load_op_library('./zero_out.so')`

this path is not inside the virtual environment folder, so I don't know if that matters.

the reason is that `.so` file cannot be found when I follow official example
[image]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b2491719b61c> in <module>
----> 1 zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('./zero_out.so')

~/Desktop/my-project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)
     56     RuntimeError: when unable to load the library or get the python wrappers.
     57   """
---> 58   lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
     59   try:
     60     wrappers = _pywrap_python_op_gen.GetPythonWrappers(

NotFoundError: ./zero_out.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This full path method is a workaround that I found in another post, I don't know in which step I went wrong unnoticed and where really should the 'built' `.so` file be located.

I have a thought that I havent tried out, do I actually have to make a new `pip package` every time I make a new custom op and `reinstall` it to the environment for the new op to work. <--- I tried this still doesnt work.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please use text to display text, not images. It allows easy searching, which is what you should do before vene posting here. That said, the title is about C++, the tags say Python, which is the case? Which is at the core (think [mcve]) of the problem?

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply ! I included text below image, I tagged Python because ultimately the c++ example code provided on tensorflow official website : ```https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op#compile_the_op_using_bazel_tensorflow_source_installation``` would be used in python, thank you very much